# How to rectify the code inside the if condition, getting an error of type mismatch and ArrayIndexOutOfBoundExceptions() shows unresolved reference

Tags: kotlin

I am new to kotlin and was trying to make insertion, deletion, and print the contents of the array. I made the insertion but under the removeAt method I am checking whether the index passed is valid then shift the elements to left.

```
`fun main() {

var a = ArrayHandling(3)
a.insertElement(10)
a.insertElement(20)
a.insertElement(30)
a.insertElement(40)
a.insertElement(50)
a.insertElement(60)
a.removeAt(2)
a.displayArray()
}

class ArrayHandling(l: Int){
var count: Int=0
var emptyArray1 = IntArray(l)
fun insertElement(element: Int):  Unit {

    if (count == emptyArray1.size) {
        val emptyArray2 = IntArray(2*count)
        for(i in 0 until count){
         emptyArray2[i]=emptyArray1[i]
        }
    emptyArray1=emptyArray2
    }

   emptyArray1[count++] = element

}

fun removeAt(index: Int): Unit {
    //validate index
    if (0< index < emptyArray1.size){
        for (i in index until emptyArray1.size){
            emptyArray1[i] = emptyArray1[i+1]
        }
    }
    else{
        throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundExceptions()
    }
}

fun displayArray(){

    for (items in 0 until count) {
        println(emptyArray1[items])
    }
    println("-----------------------------------------")
}
}`
```

if (0< index < emptyArray1.size) inside the statement emptyArray1.size raises an error of type mismatch Required: Boolean, Found: Int.
This checking is done to get a valid index where the element is to be popped else raise an exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundExceptions(), intellij is showing unresolved reference to ArrayIndexOutOfBoundExceptions().
If anymore information is needed please comment.

Comment: You have to decompose your comparison in two : `0 <= index && index < emptyArray1.size`

Comment: you can't use "two-way" checks for integers in Kotlin/ Java. either separate the two or use `in 0 until emptyArray1.size`. (basically what you have in `displayArray` already)

Comment: Thanks a lot,  and how to throw the exception I am stuck on that too.